# WebKit CSS Inspector's Style Disable Checkbox Should be Moved Left for Useability

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

Is there a way to move the checkboxes that disable CSS styles in the WebKit Inspector that is baked into Safari and Google Chrome from the far right over to the left, next to the declaration how Firefox's Firebug does it? To disable styles, one must go over to the far right, which can be hard to eye trace when the style declaration list is very long. On top of that, sometimes the new Lion style scrollbars can get accidentally clicked. I hear that even the Web Inspector in WebKit is laid out via CSS, so this should be relatively easy. Any help? Even if someone could get me to the style sheet for the WebKit inspector I could figure out the CSS. Thanks in advance!

Here's some screenshots to demonstrate what I mean:

- [WebKit CSS Inspector](https://img.skitch.com/20111129-r7sqhpkcicr94cww2mniwf2q3f.jpg)
- [Firebug CSS Inspector](https://img.skitch.com/20111129-kr1t2jpeniw3rj96h8txcceyws.jpg)

(Couldn't post images with Stack Overflow's setup as I'm a new account)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a lot harder than it used to be to inspect and modify the Inspector source. You used to be able to edit all the inspector files in /opt/google/chrome/resources/inspector/, which used to be a copy of http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector . Now, it's all bundled into a resources.pak file with no filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a webkit inspector stylesheet located at github: https://gist.github.com/1153881

Comment: Great! By copying that stylesheet and placing it into `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css` for Mac Chrome it worked great! See [here](http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/) for other locations and more details.

Comment: This style for checkboxes places them on top of arrows that expand shorthand properties. If you come up with a better style, feel free to share it in http://crbug.com/66628 (pay attention to a test case in coment #6). Should the result look really good, it will be integrated into the Web Inspector CSS.